# Keeping access to a Fedora Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, fedora, putty, remote-access

I run a Fedora instance in Amazon EC2. I can access and work on it perfectly by Putty. 
I also set *Seconds between keepalives* to 1 for not losing the connection due to inactivity (I mean in Putty).

Nevertheless, if a network/electric failure happens on my local computer, it shuts down the Putty connection, so the session logs off and the executions in the instances stop.

Can anybody help me in keeping a session alive and being able to connect/disconnect to it whenever I want?

Answer (score 5):

Use the [screen](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-to-use-screen-command-under-linux.html) command.

Comment: Great !  A vote up or "right answer" flag would be appreciated ;-)